# Prove $(x^3+3)(y^3+3)(z^3+3) > (x+y+z)^3$ for non-negative reals

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I've been stuck on this inequality.

Prove:
$$(x^3+3)(y^3+3)(z^3+3) > (x+y+z)^3$$
for $x,y,z \in \Bbb{R}$ and non-negative.

I tried to run through with the AM-GM method, different factorisations but to no avail. For example, I ended up with:

$$(x+y+z)^3 \geq 27xyz$$
and $$(x^3+3)(y^3+3)(z^3+3) \geq 54(2)^{1/3}xyz$$

Comment: Show that $\prod(x^3 + 3) > \prod (x^3 + 2) \geq (x+y+z)^3$. (The latter follows from holder, or expand out and AM-GM)

Comment: which variables did you use for AM-GM?

Comment: The "obvious" ones. Just write it out.

Answer (score 2):

[Holder's Inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/holders-inequality/)

**Hint:**
$$(x^3+2)(y^3+2)(z^2+2)=(x^3+1+1)(1+y^3+1)(1+1+z^3)$$

Comment: is there other (say, HS as opposed to uni lvl) methods? i haven't used this before & am reading abt it now

Comment: update: i used the inequality, however, i am unsure if i can remove the equality sign. is there a way to show it is strictly greater than?

Comment: Holder's is a standard tool in Olympiad math. I am sure you will get the hang of it after looking at a few examples.

Comment: Note, in your question the LHS is $(x^3+3)(y^3+3)(z^3+3)$ which is slightly different from the LHS of the inequality that you have already proved. So, it remains to show that..... ??

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, we WTS

$$(x^3 + 2)(y^3+2)(z^3+2) = x^3y^3z^3 + \sum 2x^3y^3 + \sum 4x^3 + 8 \\
\geq \\
(x+y+z)^3 = \sum x^3 + 3\sum x^2 y + 3\sum xy^2 + 6 xyz. $$

OP asks how we can apply AM-GM, and I indicate to "do the obvious":

> $x^3 y^3 z^3 + 1 + 1 \geq 3xyz$
>  $x^3y^3 + x^3 + 1 \geq 3x^2y$  - and cyclic permutations
>  $x^3y^3 + y^3 + 1 \geq 3xy^2 $  - and cyclic permutations
>  $x^3 + y^3 + z^3  \geq  3xyz $